# Examples Of Unconventional Batteries

Tags: famous-games, discovered-check

I recently played a funny [blitz game on Lichess as White](https://lichess.org/XYtzzbyn/white) in which an usual battery was formed.

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "25"]

1. d4 e5 2. dxe5 Nc6 3. e4 Nxe5 4. Nf3 d6 5. Nxe5 dxe5 6. Qxd8+ Kxd8 7. Bc4 Bc5  8. Bxf7 Nf6 9. O-O Nxe4 10. Bb3 Nxf2 11. Rxf2 Rf8 12. Nc3 Bxf2+ 13. Kh1 Be1 14.  Bg5+ Ke8 15. Rxe1 Be6 16. Bxe6
```

Black preceded to play 13... Be1, unwittingly creating a battery for me with two pieces that had never moved before. I repeat, **a self-creating battery with two unmoved pieces forming the battery itself.** Quite funny indeed.

I define a battery in this case as “when one pieces hides in front in front of a queen, rook, or bishop, and that hiding piece moves/threatens to move with a threat from the unmoving piece, aka a discovered attack.”

Thus, batteries in the sense of something like Alekhine’s Gun are not in the picture here.

What are some examples of unconventional, i.e rare or uncommon to see in games, not typically played, or is there a general consensus of it being so, of such a battery from famous play under the set definition? The battery is not required to have been fired-just to have existed is enough. It doesn’t have to be a check. Threatening a piece, such as in my game, is optional.

Sorry of this comes across on too broad-I will edit the question in the morning if need be.

EDIT: In regards to my particular used definition of a "battery," given that it has a few meanings, I turn to an authoritive source: Tim Krabbe. See below.

```
[Title "The Asaba Battery, White plays and makes a draw, E. Asaba, 1980"]
[FEN "4b2k/3p3B/8/8/8/n6P/p2nP3/6RK w - - 0 1"]
 [startply "15"]

1. Bg8 d5 2. Bxd5 Bc6 3. Bxc6 Ndb1 4. Rg8+ Kh7 5. Be4+ Kh6 6. Rg6+ Kh5 7. Bd5 a1=Q 8. Bf7 Kh4 9. Kg2 Kh5 10. Kh1 Kh4 11. Kg2
```

This is from Tim Krabbey article ["De Asaba-Batterij," which translates to "The Asaba Battery."](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/admag/asaba.htm).

The formation of the White rook and bishop is what is calls "The Asaba **Battery**."

The rook hides the bishop. The threat from White is, if Black moves their newfound queen, the hiding piece, the rook, moves, giving an attack to the Black king from the unmoving Bishop, aka a discovered attack.

Tim Krabbe calls and rook-bishop formation a battery, and the threat that this battery contains is the same as my chosen usage of battery for this question . Therefore, my usage of "battery" upolds; I have merely chosen one of it's many definitions to use for this questions.

In addition, many thanks to @itub in the comments for this. "The definition given by the Oxford Companion to Chess: "BATTERY, a problem term for one of the two kinds of ambush: a line-piece would command a line if another man of the same colour were moved off that line. Discovered checks arise from this kind 
of ambush, as shown in the Indian theme. Players occasionally use the word battery to describe doubled or tripled line-pieces; composers rarely 
use the word in this sense."

Alekhine's Gun is a battery of the second definition-doubling/tripling of similarly attack pieces on a rank, file, or diagonal. I am using "battery" in the sense of the discovered attacks of the first definition. This is why I stated earlier "Thus, batteries in the sense of something like Alekhine’s Gun are not in the picture here."

I hope that this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98558/discussion-on-question-by-rewan-demontay-examples-of-unconventional-batteries).

Comment: Don't you just love how people downvote helpful information on this website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty common.

With your given stipulation, the battery can only happen with a pawn as the front piece or with an attacking queen or rook masked by a bishop, knight or king along the first rank.

This example of the latter is a very old theoretical line in the Danish double-gambit:

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "14"]

1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. c3 dxc3 4. Bc4 cxb2 5. Bxb2 d5 6. Bxd5 Nf6 7. Bxf7 Kxf7 8. Qxd8 Bb4
```

The Rh8-Bf8 battery is activated at once by Black to win the queen back and reach an equal endgame.

There are even more examples of the former, e.g. this miniature played multiple times in youth tournaments:

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "7"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nd4 4. Nxe5 Qg5 5. Nxf7 Qxg2 6. Rf1 Qxe4 7.Be2 Nf3#
```

4...Qg5 jumps into the Bc1-Pd2 battery.

Answer (score 2):

Another famous example is [Edward Lasker - George Alan Thomas, 1912](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1259009). Most people remember it for the king hunt, but indeed the (non-castling) mating move is unleashing a king-rook battery.

```
[Title "Lasker-Thomas 1912"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "34"]
1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 f5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. Bxf6 Bxf6 6. e4 fxe4 7. Nxe4 b6 8. Ne5 O-O 9. Bd3 Bb7 10. Qh5 Qe7 11. Qxh7+ Kxh7 12. Nxf6+ Kh6 13. Neg4+ Kg5 14. h4+ Kf4 15. g3+ Kf3 16. Be2+ Kg2 17. Rh2+ Kg1 18. Kd2# 1-0
```